# Issue with jQuery Calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form for calculating the requirements of product to be manufactured, fisrtly, im not that great with javascript, secondly i dont know if there is a simpler way to write this function.

Basically what happens, the user will fill out the first 6 fields show in the form and then click calculate, i am also using the jquery validation plugin for the form, however the client has requested that an error message shows up if one of the calculated values is 0 or Nan.

I had the function working fine, but now i have to double click twice if there are any errors, i have a hidden  which displays when the form is loaded (it shouldn't) and i have also added a blue border if the values which have been calculated are correct and red borders if they are incorrect, below is the function and the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('#calculate').click(function() {
 var perlength = $("#plength").val();
 var pwidth = $("#pwidth").val();
 var nbeams = $("#nbeams").val();
 var hbeams = $("#hbeams").val();
 var wbeams = $("#wbeams").val();
 var nstrips = $("#nstrips").val();

 var nspacebeams = nbeams - 1;
 var beamspace = perlength - wbeams / 1000;
 var mbeamspace = beamspace / nspacebeams;
 var disbeams = mbeamspace - wbeams / 1000;
 var hbeamsc = hbeams / 1000;
 var hbeams2 = hbeamsc * hbeamsc;
 var disbeams2 = disbeams * disbeams;
 var weavediag = hbeams2 + disbeams2;
 var weavediaglength = Math.sqrt(weavediag);
 var ldiagstrips = nspacebeams * weavediaglength;
 var wbeammm = wbeams / 1000;
 var lbeamwidth = nbeams * wbeammm;
 var minlength = ldiagstrips + lbeamwidth;
 var totallength = minlength + 0.5;
 var finaltotallength = totallength.toFixed(2);
 var mainwidth = pwidth / nstrips;
 var widthfinal = mainwidth - 0.01;
 var mainwidthfinal = widthfinal.toFixed(3);
 var totalsize = (perlength * pwidth).toFixed(2);

 if ($.isNumeric($("#tpwidth").val())) {
     $("#tplength").css("border", "1px solid #008fc9");
     $("#tpwidth").css("border", "1px solid #008fc9");
     $("#totalsize").css("border", "1px solid #008fc9");
     $('#errorinput').hide();
 }

 // Else if the value is equal to 7, add a green border
 else {
     $("#tplength").css("border", "4px solid red");
     $("#tpwidth").css("border", "4px solid red");
     $("#totalsize").css("border", "4px solid red");
     $('#errorinput').show('slow');

 }


 $("#tplength").val(finaltotallength);  
 $("#tpwidth").val(mainwidthfinal);
 $("#totalsize").val(totalsize);


 });
 </script>
```

And this is the form:

```
<form action="order.cfm" method="post">
<fieldset>

<label for="plength">Pergola Length in Metres:</label>
<input name="plength" id="plength" type="text" size="25" placeholder="Pergola Length in Metres" title="Please Enter The Length Of The Pergola" />


<label for="pwidth">Pergola Width in Metres:</label>
<input name="pwidth" id="pwidth" type="text" size="25" placeholder="Pergola Width in Metres" title="Please Enter The Width Of The Pergola" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>

<label for="nbeams">Number Of Beams:</label>
<input name="nbeams" id="nbeams" type="text" size="25" placeholder="Number Of Beams" title="Please Enter The Number Of Beams"/>


<label for="hbeams">Height Of Beams in Millimetres:</label>
<input name="hbeams" id="hbeams" type="text" size="25" placeholder="Height Of Beams in Millimetres" title="Please Enter The Height Of The Beams" />

<label for="wbeams">Width Of Beams in Millimetres:</label>
<input name="wbeams" id="wbeams" type="text" size="25" placeholder="Width Of Beams in Millimetres" title="Please Enter The Width Of The Beams" />


<label for="nstrips">Number Of Weave Strips:</label>
<input name="nstrips" id="nstrips" type="text" size="25" placeholder="Number Of Weave Strips" title="Please Enter The Number Of Weave Strips" />


<p style="padding:5px 0px; margin:10px 24px 20px 0; border-bottom:5px solid #999;">
<label for="calculate"><a id="calculate" class="btn-small btn">Calculate</a></label> 
</p>



<span id="errorinput" class="error" style="margin:0 20px 20px 0; clear:both; font-size:0.8em; display:block; line-height:1.4em; padding:10px; background-color:#e3e2e2; "><i class="fa fa-times"></i> <strong>ERROR</strong> -
 All fields have not been filled out, please fill out all the fields above and click calculate.
</span>

<label for="tplength"><strong>TOTAL LENGTH REQUIRED:</strong></label>
<input name="tplength" id="tplength" style="font-size:1.3em; font-weight:500; color:#008fc9;" type="text" size="25"  placeholder="Length Required" readonly="readonly"/>

<label for="tpwidth"><strong>WIDTH OF WEAVE STRIPS (IDEAL SIZE TO BE BETWEEN 45cm - 70cm):</strong></label>
<input name="tpwidth" id="tpwidth" style="font-size:1.3em; font-weight:500; color:#008fc9;" type="text" size="25" class="weave-input" placeholder="Width Of Weave Strips" readonly="readonly" />

<span style="background-color:#263e8d; padding:10px; color:#fff; font-size:0.7em; display:block; margin-bottom:20px; width:93%; float:left;"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> IF WIDTH IS NOT BETWEEN THE IDEAL RANGE THEN YOU CAN CHANGE THE NUMBER OF WEAVE STRIPS AND CLICK ON CALCUATE AGAIN.</span>

<span id="sizeerror"></span>

<label for="totalsize"><strong>TOTAL m&sup2;:</strong></label>
<input name="totalsize" id="totalsize" style="font-size:1.3em; font-weight:500; color:#008fc9;" type="text" size="25"  placeholder="Total Size" readonly="readonly"/> 
<span id="#errorcalc1"></span>


 <br />

</fieldset>

     </form>
```

Im sorry if this is rather long, i have pasted all the information regarding this function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having pasted your HTML and jQuery into JS Fiddle (link: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mqw0u5hw/) it appears you've either got horrendously malformed HTML, or you've left some important details out of your question which would explain why your HTML looks as it does, when it's run. Could you either update your question to provide all relevant information or tidy up your HTML so that it's valid? (Ideally both.)

Comment: Hi David, thanks for getting back to me. The site is built in adobe coldfusion. Can i send you a link to the page via email so you can see what is going on with it?

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have some strange code in your html elements, I removed them but just to take a good look at your code:

```
<cfif isdefined ('url.error')>value="<cfoutput>#url.plength#</cfoutput>"     </cfif>
```

I think the following example is working fine (or at least closest to resolve your problem as I understood it): [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/benjamingranados/u92p34nd/)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thank you for getting back to me. I tried your fiddle and it works if all the fields are empty, the site is written in Adobe Coldfusion, that's why there were <cfif> codes in the inputs. The problem is that if you fill out all the fields except one and then click calculate, this field: "WIDTH OF WEAVE STRIPS (IDEAL SIZE TO BE BETWEEN 45cm - 70cm): " will display Infinity, if it shows infinity then it should highlight the field with a red border and show the error message on the top.